# Why can't I use Function.prototype.apply on Express' app.use?

Tags: javascript, express

I just noticed that for example `app.use.apply(null, ['/', f => f]);`

Will throw a TypeError

```
 TypeError: Cannot read property 'lazyrouter' of null
  at use (node_modules/express/lib/application.js:214:7)
```

Assuming that my express app instance is properly setup, what am I doing wrong?  I think that's the proper arrity? `app.use([path], cb)`
http://expressjs.com/en/guide/using-middleware.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `apply()` will change the `this` in the function.For the `app.use()` the `this` direct to the instance of the `app`, but you set it to `null`, and there no `use` function property attached on `null`, so there throw a error.

Answer (score 1):

When a function is called as a method of an object, as in `app.use([path], cb)`, within the function call the `this` keyword gets bound to the object.  The first argument to `apply` is the `this` binding you want to provide, so you need to write `app.use.apply(app, ['/', f => f]);`.